# Find all programms, written on python3 + gtk3, installed on my linux system

Tags: python-3.x, linux, gtk3

I'm practicing in GTK3-based GUI development on python3 and since I'm beginner both in programming or python or GTK3-framefork, I wish to look at examples of serious working programs written this way. My current desktop OS is Linux Mint 19.3 with XFCE environment, and I see that several graphical utilities included with distro built on GTK3 library.

So I assume the most dumb but simple way to get what I want is grepping all text files at `/usr/share/*` which contains
`import gi` or `gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")` or `from gi.repository import Gtk` lines.

But, may be there is more elegant and intelligent way to find desired packages by using package management systems (`pip` or `apt`-derivated)? I'm afraid that potentially interesting packages will be turned out of `grep` scope, because they are installed at any other unusual directory or using different importing instructions.

Comment: When I read your question, the first thing which comes in mind is the `strings` UNIX command: this shows the ASCII-alike strings within a binary. It's not elegant at all, but maybe it might help you.

Comment: FWIW, when I started Gtk and Python development, I started with the basics in tutorials. I only looked at some of the other apps when I got stuck, but knew I had seen that feature in an app I used. Most times, the code isn't as important as the idea. There's a famous saying "Show me the code, and you'll puzzle me for hours. Show me what it does and I'll duplicate it."

Comment: @theGtknerd that is awesome   